# C++ preprocess macro with 2 arguments

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have the following macro:

```
 #define LOG(level,text)
```

I want to define macro which includes both level and text:

```
#define MY_LOG_MESSAGE LEVEL1,"This is my log"
```

so latter I can run:

```
  LOG(MY_LOG_MESSAGE);
```

gcc issues preprocess error:

> error: macro "LOG" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `LOG` expand to?

Comment: @trojanfoe It fails preprocess

Comment: If this is actually about logging and not just an example, I would seriously suggest using a proper logging library, e.g. [Boost.Log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html), instead of rolling your own. Especially if it's preprocessor-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a define for each log message anyways, maybe do it like this:

`#define LOG_MY_MESSAGE LOG(LEVEL1, "This is my log")`

And use in code simply as

`LOG_MY_MESSAGE`

Comment: This probably could work, but I have several macros as LOG(). In your solution I'll need to define LOG_MY_MESSAGE per LOG macro.

Comment: @dimba No you don't, you can use the LOG()-macros as a parameter. So let's use `#define LOG_MY_MESSAGE(logger) logger(LEVEL1, "This is my log")`. In your code you can use it writing `LOG_MY_MESSAGE(LOG)`

Comment: There are several similar solution, but you was first.

Answer (score 3):

You have to convince the preprocesor to expand the `MY_LOG_MESSAGE` macro before it tries to expand `LOG()`. This [can be done](http://ideone.com/ISmmNi) by using a simple helper macro:

```
#define LOG1(x) LOG(x)

LOG1(MY_LOG_MESSAGE);
```

The arguments given to `LOG1()` are expanded in it's body, leading to a valid call for `LOG()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to [sth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510809/1111371), but allows using either one or two parameters:

```
#define LOG_(level,text) implementation
#define LOG(...) LOG_(__VA_ARGS__)

#define MY_LOG_MESSAGE LEVEL1,"This is my log"

LOG(MY_LOG_MESSAGE);
LOG(LEVEL2, "Another log");
```

The point is that `LOG` causes the parameter to be expanded before calling `LOG_`, thus giving it two parameters in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work this way. For the preprocessor you are giving only one argument to the `LOG` MACRO when it needs two.

You can solve it by doing something a bit easier:

```
#define MY_LOG_MESSAGE LOG(LEVEL1, "This is my log")
```

And use it like:

```
MY_LOG_MESSAGE
```

---

Explanation:

In the case:

```
#define LOG(level,text)

#define MY_LOG_MESSAGE LEVEL1,"This is my log"

LOG(MY_LOG_MESSAGE);
```

The preprocessor will not replace your Macro `MY_LOG_MESSAGE` when it see the call to `LOG`, it will pass it as argument (like a function).

It is only after that, when the preprocessor will replace the `LOG` macro that it will rescan the *replacement-list* to see if there is more macro to process.

From the standard :

> **16.3.1 Argument substitution [cpp.subst]**
>
> 1. **After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument substitution takes place.** A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token (see below), is replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.

It is said here that the macros passed as argument of another macro are expanded **after** that the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified.

Then you can also force preprocessor to expand the macros:

```
#define LOG(level, text)  whatever
#define MY_LOG_MESSAGE LEVEL1,"This is my log"

#define LOG_LVL1(args) LOG(args)
//               ^^^^      ^^^^
//          Pass a macro   Will be expanded by the preprocessor here
//                         And LOG will receive the correct number of arguments
LOG_LVL1(MY_LOG_MESSAGE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define ELOG(message) log(LEVEL_ERR,message)
#define WLOG(message) log(LEVEL_WARN,message)
```

so that you can use it as

`ELOG("This is error msg")` or `WLOG("Warning msg")`

assuming you have a function

`void log(int loglevel,char* msg)`

Answer (score 0):

yeah, define LOG like this:

```
 #define LOG(text)
```

then LOG receive just 1 parameter and you can use it with your message

```
LOG(MY_LOG_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: @dimba Yes you can; just override it.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor goes from the beginning of each file to the end of it, immediately replacing any macro with the replacement token list. In your case, `LOG` gets replaced first, before `MY_LOG_MESSAGE` is replaced with 2 arguments, thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

`MY_LOG_MESSAGE` will be treated as one argument by the preprocessor, because it's a preprocessor directive. `LEVEL1,"This is my log"` is contained inside your `MY_LOG_MESSAGE` and treated as a single preprocessor-argument when used in other preprocessor-directives.

For calling simple functions like

```
void DoLogging(Level level, const std::string& msg)
```

your macro will be treated as you expect it. So `DoLogging(MY_LOG_MESSAGE)` will work. It will expand here, because it's `not` used as a argument of another preprocessor-directive, but inside a `real` function. What could help is something like this:

```
#define MY_LOG_MESSAGE LOG(LEVEL1, "My message")
```

Furhtermore, if there are multiple LOG()-macros as you pointed out, just use it as a parameter of you MY_LOG_MESSAGE, like this:

```
#define MY_LOG_MESSAGE(logger) logger(LEVEL1, "My message")
```

In your code just call it `MY_LOG_MESSAGE(LOG)`